# Organize fasta file into data frame or table

Tags: r, dataframe, dataset, bioinformatics, fasta

I need to organize the fasta file in this web site
https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/?query=cytokines&sort=score into a data frame or table which contains as columns ID, Name Specie an Sequence of each protein please help me using R !!

Comment: What have you tried so far? The `read.table`  command is often first function to try when you want to read a data.frame-like file. `read.table(file="xyz", sep="abc")` might help, where xyz is your filename and abc is the seperator used in that file (could be "|" in your case).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: it's done I fixed it thank you

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded the fasta file using the interface on the web page. Then I used the Bioconductor package [Biostrings](https://bioconductor.org/packages/Biostrings)

```
install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install("Biostrings")
```

to read the fasta file as an 'AAStringSet'

```
aa <- readAAStringSet("uniprot-cytokines.fasta.gz")
```

The `names(aa)` are the names of each sequence as reported in the fasta file.

```
> head(names(aa), 3)
[1] "sp|Q8IV20|LACC1_HUMAN Purine nucleoside phosphorylase LACC1 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=LACC1 PE=1 SV=1"          
[2] "sp|Q9H257|CARD9_HUMAN Caspase recruitment domain-containing protein 9 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=CARD9 PE=1 SV=2"
[3] "sp|Q8BZT5|LRC19_MOUSE Leucine-rich repeat-containing protein 19 OS=Mus musculus OX=10090 GN=Lrrc19 PE=1 SV=1"
```

I used the dplyr and tidyr packages to extract the relevant fields using a regular expression

```
fields <-
    names(aa) |>
    dplyr::as_tibble() |>
    tidyr::extract(
        "value",
        into = c(
            "xx", "entry", "entry_name", "protien_names",
            "organism", "organism_id", "gene_names"
        ),
        regex = "^(.+)\\|(.+)\\|([^ ]+) (.*) OS=(.*) OX=(.*) GN=(.*) PE=.*$"
    )
```

resulting in

```
> fields
# A tibble: 17,166 × 7
   xx    entry  entry_name  protien_names        organism organism_id gene_names
   <chr> <chr>  <chr>       <chr>                <chr>    <chr>       <chr>     
 1 sp    Q8IV20 LACC1_HUMAN Purine nucleoside p… Homo sa… 9606        LACC1     
 2 sp    Q9H257 CARD9_HUMAN Caspase recruitment… Homo sa… 9606        CARD9     
 3 sp    Q8BZT5 LRC19_MOUSE Leucine-rich repeat… Mus mus… 10090       Lrrc19    
 4 sp    P10145 IL8_HUMAN   Interleukin-8        Homo sa… 9606        CXCL8     
 5 sp    P09429 HMGB1_HUMAN High mobility group… Homo sa… 9606        HMGB1     
 6 sp    Q9NZH7 IL36B_HUMAN Interleukin-36 beta  Homo sa… 9606        IL36B     
 7 sp    Q8IUC6 TCAM1_HUMAN TIR domain-containi… Homo sa… 9606        TICAM1    
 8 sp    Q80UF7 TCAM1_MOUSE TIR domain-containi… Mus mus… 10090       Ticam1    
 9 sp    O35718 SOCS3_MOUSE Suppressor of cytok… Mus mus… 10090       Socs3     
10 sp    P47811 MK14_MOUSE  Mitogen-activated p… Mus mus… 10090       Mapk14    
# … with 17,156 more rows
```

I then added the sequences from the `aa` object created earlier

```
> dplyr::bind_cols(fields, sequence = as.character(aa))
# A tibble: 17,166 × 8
   xx    entry entry_name protien_names organism organism_id gene_names sequence
   <chr> <chr> <chr>      <chr>         <chr>    <chr>       <chr>      <chr>   
 1 sp    Q8IV… LACC1_HUM… Purine nucle… Homo sa… 9606        LACC1      MAEAVLI…
 2 sp    Q9H2… CARD9_HUM… Caspase recr… Homo sa… 9606        CARD9      MSDYEND…
 3 sp    Q8BZ… LRC19_MOU… Leucine-rich… Mus mus… 10090       Lrrc19     MKVTRFM…
 4 sp    P101… IL8_HUMAN  Interleukin-8 Homo sa… 9606        CXCL8      MTSKLAV…
 5 sp    P094… HMGB1_HUM… High mobilit… Homo sa… 9606        HMGB1      MGKGDPK…
 6 sp    Q9NZ… IL36B_HUM… Interleukin-… Homo sa… 9606        IL36B      MNPQREA…
 7 sp    Q8IU… TCAM1_HUM… TIR domain-c… Homo sa… 9606        TICAM1     MACTGPS…
 8 sp    Q80U… TCAM1_MOU… TIR domain-c… Mus mus… 10090       Ticam1     MDNPGPS…
 9 sp    O357… SOCS3_MOU… Suppressor o… Mus mus… 10090       Socs3      MVTHSKF…
10 sp    P478… MK14_MOUSE Mitogen-acti… Mus mus… 10090       Mapk14     MSQERPT…
# … with 17,156 more rows
```

to get the desired result (knowing  that the information is all in the `aa` object, it might make more sense to work with it rather than to go through these steps).

This seems to be not quite right, because there are rows with all `NA`, probably reflecting names that do not match the regular expression...

```
> fields |> dplyr::count(xx, sort = TRUE)
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  xx        n
  <chr> <int>
1 tr    14644
2 sp     1336
3 NA     1186
```

Hmm... looks like they are missing the `GN=` (`gene_names`) element

```
> names(aa)[ids]
[1] "tr|G3QVN6|G3QVN6_GORGO C-C motif chemokine OS=Gorilla gorilla gorilla OX=9595 PE=3 SV=1"     
[2] "tr|K9IQA0|K9IQA0_DESRO C-C motif chemokine (Fragment) OS=Desmodus rotundus OX=9430 PE=2 SV=1"
[3] "tr|K9IFY6|K9IFY6_DESRO C-C motif chemokine OS=Desmodus rotundus OX=9430 PE=2 SV=1"
```

I'm not really sure how to best deal with this, e.g., separately parsing the records with and without gene names...

```
idx <- grepl("GN=", names(aa))
aa_with_gene_names <- aa[ idx ]
aa_without_gene_names <- aa[ !idx ]
```