# Organize .faa file into dataframe using tidyr::extract and a regex

Tags: r, tidyr, fasta

I'm trying to convert .faa file with 30.799 elements of protein sequences to a tabular format by separating IDs in one column, names in other column, and sequence to another column. An FAA file **stores a record of one or more nucleic acid or protein sequences saved in the FASTA format**. It can be considered as list of FASTA.

I have tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69946331/organize-fasta-file-into-data-frame-or-table) written by @[Martin Morgan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/547331/martin-morgan)

I couldn't go further due to having this issue of "Error: `regex` should define 2 groups; 4 found.". Since I did not quite understand regex, I couldn't manage to do it.

Data:
https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCF/000/001/215/GCF_000001215.4_Release_6_plus_ISO1_MT/GCF_000001215.4_Release_6_plus_ISO1_MT_protein.faa.gz

```
library(seqinr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
install.packages("BiocManager")
library(BiocManager)
BiocManager::install("Biostrings")
library(Biostrings)


url <- "https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCF/000/001/215/GCF_000001215.4_Release_6_plus_ISO1_MT/GCF_000001215.4_Release_6_plus_ISO1_MT_protein.faa.gz"
destfile <- tempfile()
download.file(url, destfile)

fruitfly <- readAAStringSet(destfile)
head(names(fruitfly), 3) #it returns good outcome. Try to separate it. 

fields <-
  names(fruitfly) |>
  dplyr::as_tibble() |>
  tidyr::extract(
    "value",
    into = c(
      "names", "seq"
    ),
    regex = "^(.+)\\|(.+)\\|([^ ]+) (.*)"
  )
```

It gives

> "Error: `regex` should define 2 groups; 4 found.". Since I did not quite understand regex, I couldn't manage to do it.

Here is an overview of the data.

```
> print(fruitfly[30796])
AAStringSet object of length 1:
    width seq                                                                                                      names               
[1]    96 MIMILYWSLPMILFILGLFCFVSNRKHLLSMLLSLEFIVLMLFFMLFIYLNMLNYESYFSMMFLTFSVCEGALGLSILVSMIRTHGNDYFQSFSIM         YP_009047275.1 NA...


> str(fruitfly)
Formal class 'AAStringSet' [package "Biostrings"] with 5 slots
  ..@ pool           :Formal class 'SharedRaw_Pool' [package "XVector"] with 2 slots
  .. .. ..@ xp_list                    :List of 1
  .. .. .. ..$ :<externalptr> 
  .. .. ..@ .link_to_cached_object_list:List of 1
  .. .. .. ..$ :<environment: 0x000002140e4d4de8> 
  ..@ ranges         :Formal class 'GroupedIRanges' [package "XVector"] with 7 slots
  .. .. ..@ group          : int [1:30799] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  .. .. ..@ start          : int [1:30799] 1 1526 3051 4186 4814 5442 5828 5945 6413 6935 ...
  .. .. ..@ width          : int [1:30799] 1525 1525 1135 628 628 386 117 468 522 294 ...
  .. .. ..@ NAMES          : chr [1:30799] "NP_001007096.1 uncharacterized protein Dmel_CG42637, isoform C [Drosophila melanogaster]" "NP_001007097.1 uncharacterized protein Dmel_CG42637, isoform B [Drosophila melanogaster]" "NP_001014453.1 phosphatase 1 nuclear targeting subunit, isoform D [Drosophila melanogaster]" "NP_001014454.1 phosphatase 1 nuclear targeting subunit, isoform A [Drosophila melanogaster]" ...
  .. .. ..@ elementType    : chr "ANY"
  .. .. ..@ elementMetadata: NULL
  .. .. ..@ metadata       : list()
  ..@ elementType    : chr "AAString"
  ..@ elementMetadata: NULL
  ..@ metadata       : list()
```

Comment: `extract` uses capture groups to make new columns. Every capture group is enclosed by `()`. You gave it two column names, so you need two capture groups, but your regex pattern has four total `()`.  You have to give it two.

Comment: I tried this one `regex = "^(.+)\\|(.+)\\ PE=.*$"`. Then it gives bunch of NAs.                
`> fields
# A tibble: 30,799 × 2
   seq   names
   <chr> <chr>
 1 NA    NA   
 2 NA    NA   
 3 NA    NA   
 4 NA    NA   
 5 NA    NA   
 6 NA    NA   
 7 NA    NA   
 8 NA    NA   
 9 NA    NA   
10 NA    NA   
# … with 30,789 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows`